# Yang model validation error. Element not allowed anywhere, expected end-tag

Tags: xml, validation, data-modeling, datamodel, ietf-netmod-yang

I have the following YANG model. I want to validate the model against custom xml data.

```
module turing-machine {

  namespace "http://example.net/turing-machine";

  prefix "tm";

  description
    "Data model for the Turing Machine.";

  revision 2013-12-27 {
    description
      "Initial revision.";
  }

  /* State data and Configuration */

  container turing-machine {
    list router {
      config false;
      leaf name {
        type string;
      }
      leaf interface {
        type string;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The xml I want to validate is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- file: turing-machine-config.xml -->
<config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <turing-machine xmlns="http://example.net/turing-machine">
    <router>
      <name>A</name>
    </router>
    <router>
      <interface>B</interface>
    </router>
  </turing-machine>
</config>
```

The validation is done using the following commands:

```
yang2dsdl -t config model.yang
trang -I rng -O rnc model-config.rng model-config.rnc
yang2dsdl -s -j -b model -t config -v data.xml
```

The validation results in:

```
Element `router` not allowed anywhere, expected element end-tag.
```

Please note that since the child elements are not common inside router and therefore I cannot use a 'config true' because I cannot choose a key, I think that a workaround is to use config false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that config is used instead of data inside the xml and inside the validation commands. A valid xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- file: turing-machine-config.xml -->
<data xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <turing-machine xmlns="http://example.net/turing-machine">
    <router>
      <name>A</name>
    </router>
    <router>
      <interface>B</interface>
    </router>
  </turing-machine>
</data>
```

Then in order to validate the following commands must be executed. Note that -t data is optional since data is the default option anyway.

```
yang2dsdl -t data model.yang
trang -I rng -O rnc model-config.rng model-config.rnc
yang2dsdl -s -j -b model -t data -v data.xml
```